# How to get 4 numbers from the user and then automatic down line

Tags: c

someone know how do i let the user enter 4 numbers and then automatic down line
like it tell the user "enter 4 numbers no enter is needed" and than the user type 1234 and in the Minute he enter the four number in the series its do \n

that what i tried alredy

```
printf("Write your guess (only 1-6, no ENTER is needed)\n");
scanf("%d%d%d%d\n", &num1,&num2,&num3,&num4);
```

Comment: How would `scanf` know where one number stops and the next picks up without a length hint?

Comment: You could create a for loop and use getch() if you are willing to use an array of num.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some kind of logic to entering number which you could later detect in code. 
 For Example : 
Ask user to enter number in 6 digits like 000121 and then you separate the number after every 6 digits.

**Another approach** would be to use time function. Wait for some time and capture the input from user.